# How to have output from lm() include std. error and others without using summary() for stargazer

Tags: r, lm, stargazer

I'm fitting several linear models in r in the following way:

```r
set.seed(12345)
n = 100
x1 = rnorm(n)
x2 = rnorm(n)+0.1
y = x + rnorm(n)

df <- data.frame(x1, x2, y)
x_str <- c("x1", "x1+x2")

regf_lm <- function(df,y_var, x_str ) {
  frmla <- formula(paste0(y_var," ~ ", x_str ))
  fit <- lm(frmla, data = df ) 
  summary(fit) #fit
}

gbind_lm <- function(vv) {
  n <-  vv %>% length()
  fits <- list()
  coefs <- list()
  ses <- list()
  for (i in 1:n ) {
    coefs[[i]] <- vv[[i]]$coefficients[,1]
    ses[[i]] <- vv[[i]]$coefficients[,2]
    fits[[i]] <- vv[[i]]
  }
  
  list("fits" = fits, "coefs" = coefs, "ses" = ses)
}
  
stargazer_lm <- function(mylist, fname, title_str,m_type = "html",...) {
    stargazer(mylist$fits, coef =  mylist$coefs,
              se = mylist$ses,
              type = m_type, title = title_str, 
              out = paste0("~/projects/outputs",fname),  single.row = T ,...)
}

p_2 <- map(x_str, 
           ~ regf_lm (df = df ,
                      y_var = "y", x_str = .))
m_all <- do.call(c, list(p_2)) %>% gbind_lm()
stargazer_lm(m_all,"name.html","My model", m_type = "html")
```

In `regf_lm`, if I use `summary(fit)` on the last line, I'm able to generate reg output with columns for estimated coefficients, std. error, etc. But Stargazer() [does not work with summary(lm())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857488/export-regression-table-with-stargazer-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors) (returns `error $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`). However, if I just use "fit" on the last line in `regf_lm`, the output shows only the estimated coefficients and not std error, R sq...and `gbind_lm()` won't work because I cannot extract ses or fit.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly export model statistics in tidy format with the package `broom`

```
library(broom)

set.seed(12345)
n = 100
x1 = rnorm(n)
x2 = rnorm(n)+0.1
y = x1 + rnorm(n)

df <- data.frame(x1, x2, y)
x_str <- c("x1", "x1+x2")

regf_lm <- function(df,y_var, x_str ) {
  frmla <- formula(paste0(y_var," ~ ", x_str ))
  fit <- lm(frmla, data = df ) 
  return(list(fit,select(broom::tidy(fit),std.error))) #fit
}

exm_model <- regf_lm(iris,'Sepal.Width','Sepal.Length')

stargazer(exm_model[[1]], coef =  exm_model[[2]], title = 'x_model', 
              out ='abc',  single.row = T)
```

This piece of code worked on my local with no problem, I think you can apply this in your workflow.

Comment: Thank you. It no longer worked with the gbind_lm function, and I tried updating it accordingly. I believe the first 2 lines in the for loop are updated correctly but I'm not sure how to deal with the last line, fits[[i]] because of the way the std errors were appended in your suggestion? ```gbind_lm <- function(vv) {
  n <-  vv %>% length()
  fits <- list()
  coefs <- list()
  ses <- list()
  for (i in 1:n ) {
    coefs[[i]] <- vv[[i]][[1]]$coefficients 
    ses[[i]] <- vv[[i]][[2]]$std.error
    fits[[i]] <- vv[[i]]
  }
  
  list("fits" = fits, "coefs" = coefs, "ses" = ses)
}```